# Facing Communication link failure to slave occasionally in Mysql master-slave replication configured with c3p0 connection pooling

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling, database-replication, c3p0

I have a Master-Slave replication configured  using Mysql replication driver along with c3p0 connection pooling. Facing the following connection failure issue in slave sometimes. In current setup there is one master and one slave.

```
   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy264.get(Unknown Source)
    /* 
    getSomeDataFromSlave()
    */      java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
            at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
            ... 16 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
            ... 18 more
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failureThe last packet successfully received from the server was 5,804 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 3,206 milliseconds ago.
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor897.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3465)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3365)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3805)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4874)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostMySQLConnection.setAutoCommit(MultiHostMySQLConnection.java:2064)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor367.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.invokeMore(LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.java:484)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostConnectionProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:452)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy232.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostMySQLConnection.setAutoCommit(MultiHostMySQLConnection.java:2064)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor367.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnectionProxy.invokeMore(ReplicationConnectionProxy.java:293)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MultiHostConnectionProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:452)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy233.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
            at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
            ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:100)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:143)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:173)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2954)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3375)
            ... 43 more
```

Here are the configuration currently:

```
**c3p0 properties:**

db.maxPoolSize=20
db.minPoolSize=10
db.maxConnectionIdleTimeInSec=300
db.idleConnectionTestPeriodInSec=300
db.testConnectionOnCheckin=true
db.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
db.connectionTestQuery=select 1

** DB config **

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql:replication://url1,url2/schema

**I have done some c3p0 finer logging following are some traces**
.....
FINER] MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[z8kflt9j9jerlpms8xe0|8ac49e] registered.

2016-09-13 12:39:51 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -

Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

[FINEST] incremented pending_acquires: 1

[FINEST] incremented pending_acquires: 2

[FINEST] incremented pending_acquires: 3

[FINER] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@37ca3e27 config: [start -> 3; min -> 3; max -> 10; inc -> 3; num_acq_attempts -> 30; acq_attempt_delay -> 1000; check_idle_resources_delay -> 60000; mox_resource_age -> 0; max_idle_time -> 100000; excess_max_idle_time -> 0; destroy_unreturned_resc_time -> 10000; expiration_enforcement_delay -> 2500; break_on_acquisition_failure -> false; debug_store_checkout_exceptions -> true]

[INFO] Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> z8kflt9j9jerlpms8xe0|8ac49e, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> z8kflt9j9jerlpms8xe0|8ac49e, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 60, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql:replication://url1,url2/schema, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 100, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> select 1, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 10, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]

[FINER] acquire test -- pool size: 0; target_pool_size: 3; desired target? 1

[FINE] awaitAvailable(): [unknown]

[
....
```

My assumption  is that slave connections in pool gets closed from Mysql side but in pool its still not updated and not marked as inactive. Assuming its an active connection application tries to fetch from slave and fails.
Any idea what could be issue here? Is it an issue with connection pool which is not testing the slave connection and refreshing the connection periodically before its being used?

Tried custom connection class for  connectionTest but no luck.Connection test class as follows

public class QueryReplicationConnectionTester extends DefaultConnectionTester{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3450145378350470297L;

/**
 * during testing we need to make sure, that not only master
 * but also the slave connection is used. Therefore we need to set
 * the connection to "readonly" to make sure, that the slave 
 * connection is used.
 * 
 * CAUTION: this will only work for ONE SLAVE ENVIRONMENT, since
 * this does not make sure all slaves are checked.
 */
@Override
public int activeCheckConnection(Connection connection, String arg1, Throwable[] arg2) {

    // Initially set to ok
    int status = CONNECTION_IS_OKAY;

    try {

        // remember state and 
        boolean autoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
        boolean readOnly = connection.isReadOnly();

        // switch to slave and check slave
        connection.setReadOnly(true);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        status = super.activeCheckConnection(connection, arg1, arg2);

        // if slave is fine, lets check the master
        if ( status == CONNECTION_IS_OKAY ){
            connection.setReadOnly(false);
            connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
            status = super.activeCheckConnection(connection, arg1, arg2);
        }

        connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
        connection.setReadOnly(readOnly);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        status = CONNECTION_IS_INVALID;
    }

    // return final state
    return status;
}
```

}

Checked Mysql logs as well. I could see preferredtestquery(select 1) being fired to master but its not fired to slave for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is what you think it is, then an easy workaround might be to set the [Connection property](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) `readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves`. Then you could use c3p0's built-in `DefaultConnectionTester`, and as long as the master is available, Connections will work. If the master goes down, then Connection tests will fail and clients will be unable to acquire Connections even from the slave until the master comes back to life. But unless all uses of your Connections are read-only, that's probably the behavior you want. If the master is down and c3p0 releases Connections to your application, it has no way to know whether those Connections will be used for read-only purposes or not, so it should consider those Connections broken. You get some load distribution through replication under this scenario, but you can't "failback" to the slave if the master is down. You should failback to the master when the slave is down, though.

If all of your application's uses of Connections are read-only, you can write a [ConnectionCustomizer](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers) that calls the `setReadOnly(true)` in its `onAcquire(...)` method. c3p0 will track overrides of `setReadOnly(...)`, and ensure that clients see the value you have set, even after check-in/check-out cycles. Then, presumably Connections would be to the slave by default. If you set `readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves`, then you're application should properly failback to the master is the slave is not available. Note that your clients should never set `setReadOnly(false)` if its use of Connections is entirely read-only.

However, it's more likely that your clients are not universally read-only, and so you should use an ordinary Connection test without setting read-only first, but with `readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves` set. Connections are then invalid when the master is down, as they should be, but should survive a problem with the slave.

I'm not sure why you aren't seeing your Connection tests intended for the slave, but you might try using `setAutoCommit(true)` rather than `setAutoCommit(false)` for the test intended for the slave in your custom `ConnectionTester`. But I think in the end, you won't want to use this Connection tester, the default Connection tester will suffice.

You might also want to set the Connection property `autoReconnect` to true.

***Note**: I haven't used MySQL's ReplicationDriver, this is all guesswork from a quick read of the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html).*

Comment: It occurred to me but is there a way that we can make sure that slave connections gets refreshed periodically?Any issue you see with the custom query connection tester?